# Rounding monetary amount to the number of decimal digits traditionally used for a currency

Tags: python, serialization, localization, currency

I want to produce an XML that looks like this:

```
<amount currency="AUD">123.00</amount>
```

I can produce that quite easily by doing "{0:.2f}".format(123) which is fine and dandy; but many currencies are traditionally not represented with two decimal points, some examples:

```
<amount currency="JPY">12345</amount>
<amount currency="KWD">12345.678</amount>
<amount currency="BTC">1.23456789</amount> # bonus point
```

I do not want end-user oriented localization like those provided by locale or babel. These user-oriented localization libraries would also localize grouping separators, decimal points, and add currency symbols, which is fine when formatting currency for displaying to the user, but those are not desirable for machine-to-machine communication as they make the parsing more difficult for the receiving machine.

The currency function from locale with symbol=False is almost what I want:

```
In [1]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ar_KW')
Out[1]: 'ar_KW'
In [2]: locale.currency(4, False)
Out[2]: '4.000'
```

But two issues:

1. I don't want to maintain a mapping from currency code KWD -> to locale code ar_KW.
2. locale.setlocale sets a global state of the program which is undesirable in a server as multiple threads may want to convert different currencies

babel's format_currency does not even use the correct number of decimal place:

```
In [3]: babel.numbers.format_currency(4, 'KWD')
Out[3]: u'KWD12.00'
```

Of course I can probably maintain such a dict by harvesting from a list like [this](http://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat), but this seems like it should be an already-solved problem.

Is there a python library that knows how to format monetary amount with the correct number of decimal places? I would expect to be able to call it like so: `to_currency(amount=Decimal('12345.67890'), currency='OMR', symbol=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> print babel.numbers.format_currency(4, 'KWD')
KWD4.000
>>> print babel.numbers.format_currency(4, 'KWD', currency_digits=False)
KWD4.00
>>> print babel.numbers.format_currency(4, 'KWD', locale="ar_KW")
د.ك.‏ 4.000
```